# Understanding L'hospital

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have some trouble understanding L'Hospital's rule. Let's say I am given the function $f(x)= \frac{2x}{5x+6x^2}$ I am interested in $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}f(x)$.

(1) $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{2}{5+12x} = \frac{2}{5}$

(2) $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{2}{5+12x} = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{0}{12} = 0$

Where's the mistake?

Comment: To get $\frac0{12}$, Christian took the derivatives of the numerator and denominator a second time.

Answer (score 5):

The second is wrong. You can only apply it when the expression is of the form $0/0$  or  something related.

To see this recall that when you have a function $g$ that is reasonably nice, then you can say for small $x$ it is true that $g(x)$ is $g(0)+ x g'(0)+ \epsilon_g (x)$ and $\epsilon_g(x)$ is very small if you now have 
$\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$ then this is
$$\frac{g(0)+ xg'(0)+\epsilon_g (x)}{h(0) + x h'(0)+\epsilon_h (x)}.$$
And thus roughly 
$$\frac{g(0)+ xg'(0)}{h(0) + x h'(0)}.$$

If $g(0)=h(0)=0$ then this reduces to
$$\frac{xg'(0)}{ x h'(0)}$$ and cancelling $x$ you get 
$$\frac{g'(0)}{  h'(0)}$$
**However** if $g(0)$ or $h(0)$ are not $0$ then you cannot make this reduction.

Comment: This is interesting. Can you give some background information why this is a condition?

Comment: Surely that condition is in every textbook that discusses this!

Comment: Google is a very knowledgeable friend in any case...

Comment: @Christian I added some quick explanation. You should however read a detailed exposition somewhere as a complement.

Answer (score 0):

The limit $(1)$ is not of type $\frac 00$ so you can't apply the L'Hospital's rule. The limit $(2)$ is simply unrelated to the previous one.